# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 while i m running?

Tags: iphone

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFDocumentManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SearchTextInPdfViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in BasicLauncherController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_MFDocumentViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DocumentViewController in DocumentViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFDocumentViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_DocumentViewController in DocumentViewController.o
  "_initProfile", referenced from:
      -[SearchManager startSearchOperationForSearchTerm:andPage:] in SearchManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0):

You've likely forgotten to add all of the necessary frameworks for your project.

Ensure you've added any frameworks your app depends on.  To do this, in the left sidebar click the project at the very top, then select your target, and click the "Build Phases" tab.  Then expand "Link Binary with Libraries", and add the frameworks here.